# How to write Processor impl class in Kafka 2.0

Tags: scala, apache-kafka-streams

I am getting this error in Kafka 2.0 while the code is working fine for Kafka 1.1

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TopologyException: Invalid topology: Processor callmanagerprocessor must have at least one parent"
```

My code is working fine in Kafka 1.1 not sure what I need to change for 2.0

```
class CallManagersProcessor extends Processor[String, String] with Logging {
  private var context: ProcessorContext = _

  var callManagersProcessorCounter:Long = 0

  override def init(processorContext: ProcessorContext): Unit = {
    this.context = processorContext
    StreamConstants.callManagerStore = Option(context.getStateStore(CallManagersProcessor.STORE).asInstanceOf[KeyValueStore[String, CallManager]])
  }

  override def process(key: String, value: String): Unit = {

    logger.info("callManagersProcessorCounter ="+callManagersProcessorCounter )

    callManagersProcessorCounter = callManagersProcessorCounter +1
    val cmKey = processManagerKey(key)
    if (cmKey.isDefined) {
      val cmValue = processManagerValue(value)
      if (cmValue.isDefined) {

        StreamConstants.callManagerStore.get.put(cmKey.get,cmValue.get)
        context.forward(cmKey.get, cmValue.get.toJson.toString())
      } else {

        StreamConstants.callManagerStore.get.put(cmKey.get,null)
        context.forward(cmKey.get, null)
      }
    }

  }
```

Topology code:

```
class DimensionTopology(streamName: String) extends TopologyProvider with Logging {
  override val name: String = streamName
  val objectSerdes: Serde[Object] = Serdes.serdeFrom(new ObjectSerializer(), new ObjectDeserializer())
  override type BuilderType = Topology

  //Processor API
  override def topology(builder: BuilderType, source: String, sink: String): Topology = {

    val callManagersProcessor: ProcessorSupplier[String, String] = () => new CallManagersProcessor()
    val customersProcessor: ProcessorSupplier[String, String] = () => new CustomersProcessor()


    builder.addProcessor(CallManagersProcessor.PROCESSOR, callManagersProcessor)
      .addGlobalStore( Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(
        Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(CallManagersProcessor.STORE),
        objectSerdes,
        objectSerdes
      ).withLoggingDisabled(),
        CallManagersProcessor.SOURCE,
        Serdes.String().deserializer(),
        Serdes.String().deserializer(),
        CallManagersProcessor.INPUT_TOPIC,
        CallManagersProcessor.GLOBAL_STORE,
        callManagersProcessor)
      .addSink(CallManagersProcessor.SINK, CallManagersProcessor.OUTPUT_TOPIC,
        Serdes.String().serializer(), Serdes.String().serializer(), CallManagersProcessor.PROCESSOR)


      .addSource(CallDetailsProcessor.SOURCE,Serdes.String().deserializer(), Serdes.String().deserializer(), CallDetailsProcessor.INPUT_TOPIC)
            .addProcessor(CallDetailsProcessor.PROCESSOR, new ProcessorSupplier[String, String] {
              override def get(): Processor[String, String] = {
                new CallDetailsProcessor()
              }
            }, CallDetailsProcessor.SOURCE)
            .addSink(CallDetailsProcessor.SINK, CallDetailsProcessor.OUTPUT_TOPIC,
              Serdes.String().serializer(), Serdes.String().serializer(), CallDetailsProcessor.PROCESSOR)


    builder
  }

  override def createBuilder(): BuilderType = new Topology
}

object DimensionTopology{

}
```

Comment: It seems that the processor does not have a parent node specified: `builder.addProcessor(CallManagersProcessor.PROCESSOR, callManagersProcessor)` requires a third parameter -- what is unclear to me atm is, why the code worked in 1.1 -- it should never have worked.

Comment: Its  work fine in Kafka 1.1 for Globalstate store . Yes now I am also looking why in working in 1.1 instead of throwing exception,

Comment: well what is my requirement i want get data from this topic and want to store as global store with key value and data come from the other topic it can take data from globalstore for the any key join if required.